# Testing Ajax Request in Cakephp 2.0

Tags: ajax, unit-testing, testing, cakephp-2.0

I have an action in my controller which does something only if the request is an XmlHttpRequest, like this:

```
function myAction() {
    if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

What would a TestCase for this action look like? Is there a way to mock up the CakeRequest instance to appear as an Ajax request?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it is a good way or not, but adding

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

at the top of the test method will do the job. In this case we send data as Ajax so not need to check any more.

Comment: Apparently this is the accepted way to do this. The `$_SERVER` variable is reset before each test so should not bleed into other tests or the test runner itself ([source](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648-cakephp/tickets/2819-more-flexibility-for-controller-testing-mocking-cakerequest))

Answer (score 0):

we use a trick to solve ajax unit test for cake2.0

as cake supoprts .json extention,  we create a function in AppModel to cheat ajax call. like

```
public function isAjax() {
    return $this->request->isAjax() || $this->request->ext == 'json';
}
```

Then in controller, instead of calling $this->request->isAjax(), $this->isAjax() is used.

When testing action with ajax call, we simply add suffix .json to the action call, For example,

```
    $this->testAction('/users/register');
```

This might not be the ultimate solution for ajax call test, but could be a workaround